# Retrieving list of Facebook friends who use iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-friends

I'd like to target a message to my Facebook friends who use iOS, and separately, Android.  If I'm going to recommend them a particular app, for example, I'd like to ping only those who have the right OS.  Presumably Facebook has this information.  Is there a way for me to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think Facebook would expose this kind of information on their API. What you could do is use [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/index) and its `Installation` class. By doing so, you will get specific device information of each of your users. Then you can use the [Parse Push SDK](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS) to target specific users based on this information. As an added bonus, Parse also offers Facebook integration, so it might be the tool you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook Message dialog for iOS and Android to let people send messages to their friends via Facebook Messenger. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

However, in v2.0 of the API there is no way to find out which of a users non-app-using friends are using Facebook on which platform - and in any case, the dialogs don't let you pre-fill the recipients.

If you want people to invite their friends, but want the recipient to end up being redirected to the correct (iOS or Android) version of your app, I suggest sharing the same URL, and then doing user-agent detection when someone clicks on the link to determine if you want to redirect the users to Google Play or the Apple App Store. Services like Deeplink.me may provide this as a hosted service: https://www.deeplink.me/